# Where to find cordova.jar file?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2.1

I am developing Sencha Touch 2 application using Eclipse. I want to do native packaging using cordova. All the tutorials tell to paste cordova.jar file to /lib. But I am unable to find cordova.jar file. Where can I find cordova.jar file. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Latest cordova project using cordova library project to support your main project. It called `xxxxxx-CordovaLib`. When you import your project into your eclipse, you need two projects, one is main project that contain all your cordova plugin and www files and another one is cordova library project. Without it, you will got an error.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is search for the classes.jar file when I created a PhoneGap project with CLI. But here is the [file it self](https://github.com/teusinkorg/jpHolo/tree/master/libs) (in my project on GitHub).